# Filtering in datagrid in .net

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have developed a Windows application which  has one DataGrid. I am assigning Defaultview of on datatable as datasource to that datagrid.

Then after based on some filter criteria I derived a DataView from the DataGrid 's DataSource and then applying the filter to that view and then assigned that view to grid.

It works perfectly fine.

Now when i again populate that grid with the full set of data on refresh button after clearing data in the DataSource of the grid, the filter condition is not cleared, it still persists.

So only subset of data is being displayed even though I have refreshed.

Please let me know how to clear the rowfilter while refreshing.....

Thanks......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clear a filter on a DataView, set its `RowFilter` property to an empty string:

```
yourDataView.DefaultView.RowFilter = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

First make the filter criteria to be assigned to a global variable, and on the Click of refresh button event handler, you assign some empty string to that global variable. This will surely solves your problem.